# ASP.Net Identity 2, HttpRequestBase.LogonUserIdentity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Using the ASP.Net Identity 2 provider model in conjunction with plain `Authorize` attributes.

Anonymous access is true, Windows authentication is disabled.

`HttpRequestBase.IsAuthenticated` will return true, how-ever, the `HttpRequestBase.LogonUserIdentity` will not return the actual `ClaimsIdentity` but instead an impersonated user (me as I'm running IIS Express locally).

The actual authenticated and returned `ClaimsIdentity` from the provider is accessible via e.g.

`HttpContext.Current.User...` and/or `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal...`

Q: Why not via `HttpRequestBase.LogonUserIdentity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time I see this property used. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.logonuseridentity(v=vs.110).aspx) says this property should return `WindowsIdentity` of the current user. MVC app does not know about `WindowsIdentity` of the logged in user, because there is no such thing.

Also in [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/HttpRequest.cs#2514) for this property [eventually](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/WorkerRequest.cs#582) asks for server variables.

I usually access currently logged-in user via `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` and never seen user retrieved from `HttpRequestBase.LogonUserIdentity`.
Also `HttpRequestBase.IsAuthenticated` is [identical](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/HttpRequest.cs#1356) to calling `HttpContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated` with few null-checks.

Comment: Just think the name `LogonUserIdentity` kind of implies "The loged on users identity" ;-)

Comment: It does! Name is misleading, same way `IdentityUser.LockoutEnabled` is not a flag for user being currently locked-out. Naming is hard and causes problems.